# JavaScript regex to find string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and two words from a dictionary and I am trying to know if in my string there are words that are not  my dictionary words.

```
var string = 'foobarfooba';

var patt = new RegExp("[^(foo|bar)]");// words from dictionary
var res = patt.test(string);


console.log(res);//return false
```

It should return true because in my string there is also 'ba', but it return false.

Comment: Lose the square brackets. You're not looking for a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: `var patt = /foo|bar/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as **[Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)** commented in your question, you have to get rid of the character class:

```
[^(foo|bar)]
^-- here --^
```

Character classes are used to match (or not match if you use `^`) specific unsorted characters.

Just use:

```
var patt = new RegExp("(?:foo|bar)");// words from dictionary
```

If you want to ensure that all the string matches your regex, you can use:

```
^(?:foo|bar)+$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS5eX9/1)**

If you want to capture the invalid words, you can use a regex with capturing groups like this:

```
^(?:foo|bar)+|(.+)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS5eX9/2)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [9-11]  `ba`
```

Comment: But I need to know if there are some string like 'ba' that is different of my word

Comment: it still returns false

Comment: @Giuseppefederico that's ok, it returns false because there are words not matching your regex. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well, I need to know that there is 'ba' that it is not in my regex

Comment: I am sorry you are right, could you explain me the meaning of ?: and +$

Comment: @Giuseppefederico The meaning of `(?:` is just to tell regex engine to not capture the content of the group, if you remove `?:` then you will capture. It will useful to capture the content if you want to have the existing words. On the other hand, the `+` is applied to the group to tell that you can have multiple occurrences of your words. And the ending `$` is just an anchor to say that the regex engine must find and end of string. Check debuggex diagram to have it clear ![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/QT7dXtb5nR5qRcTJ.png)

Comment: ok perfect, but I don't understand $ meaning. It is used to find at the end of a string, but we are searhing in all string

Comment: @Giuseppefederico this of this: `^foobar$` it means that your string must start and end with `foobar`, if you have `foobar$` your string must end with `foobar` so `xxxfoobar` will be valid.

Comment: with that  `^(?:foo|bar)+|(.+)$` I can only match string after foo or bar, how can I match string before foo or bar?

Comment: @Giuseppefederico I don't find a way since regex engine can't know if `ar` or `arbar` it's a wrong question. I'm checking at this and will get back to you. However, you can post another question explaining what you have and what your problem is to know if community can come up with new ideas. Anyway, I'll try to find a solution too.